# Interpolation doesn't work on first load of the page

Tags: angular, promise, ionic2, interpolation

After a login where the user types his name and clicks login, the next page doesn't show the name. If he goes back and retries, it works then and afterwards.

ON THE HTML TEMPLATE:

```
<ion-title>Your name is {{name}}</ion-title>
```

ON THE COMPONENT:

```
  name: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {this.name= val;});
  }
```

Comment: when is it stored in `this.storage`? Can you add that part?

Comment: in the previous login page. I mean everything works fine, except the first time the site is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are pushing the next page outside of then of `storage.set()` part. Since, I do not have access to your code, demonstrating how it should be done. I am sure this will work:

```
this.storage.set('name',"somename")
 .then((val) => {
   console.log("Value is set to somename");
   this.navCtrl.push(NextPage);
 });
```

This is to be done on the previous page where you are setting the value in the storage.

In this case, it is assured that you navigate to the next page only when the value is set.

Answer (score 0):

when user logged in, you could public an event (Ionic event), in your component, just subscribe to the event you defined. whenever event fire, you could update your property.

your app does not work, because, at the early state, the storage does not persist any data, even you get from storage, it's nothing.

```
constructor(
    private events: Events,
    private storage: Storage,
    //...
) { } 

login(/* params */) {
  // after login successful, save name to storage
  this.storage.set('name', JSON.stringify(name))
    .subscribe(() => {
      this.events.publish('login:success');
    });
}
```

ON THE COMPONENT:

```
name: string;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private storage: Storage, private events: Events) {
    this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {this.name= val;});
    this.event.subscribe('login:success', () => {
      this.storage.get('name').then((val) => {this.name= val;});
    })
  }
}
```